# how to read and write into a file using streamwriter and streamreader

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to read the content from a .csv file and storing it in a variable. Later I am writing that content into a newfile. Code is executing successfully but the data is not appearing in new file. Any suggestions please?

Here is my code:

```
    Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")

    Dim ioLine As String 
    Dim ioLines As String 
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
    ioLines = ioLine
    While Not ioLine = ""
        ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
        ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine

    End While
    Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")
    ioWriter.WriteLine(ioLines)
    ioFile.Close()
    ioWriter.Close()
```

Comment: It is working fine now. I dont know why it wasn't worked before. Sorry for giving trouble to you all

Answer (score 4):

There are some very short and very good tutorials on the MSDN site:

1. [How to: Write text to a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [How to: Read text from a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer , cos I had the same problem like U.
Below I share you my source code. It works,  try it.

```
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(path + "\" + fileName) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(path + "\" + fileName).Dispose()
    End If

    Dim sr As New StreamReader(path + "\" + fileName)
    Dim NumberOfLines As Integer

    Do While sr.Peek >= 0
        sr.ReadLine()
        NumberOfLines += 1
    Loop
    NumberOfLines = NumberOfLines + 1
    sr.Close()
    sr.Dispose()

    Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file_path, False)
    sw.WriteLine(NumberOfLines.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") + vbTab + "Your content")
    sw.Close()
    sw.Dispose()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more as to what the code is doing and why it solves his problem

Comment: Sure, First I check if the txt file exists, if it doesn't exist, I create it.

then, if I had streamreader and streamwriter in the same code an error message was thrown "File In Use By Another Process".

So, the key is close the file and release the streamreader memory object after use it. sr.Close() sr.Dispose()

After that, we can use them in the same code without any problem.

The variable value in NumberOfLines was used to number the lines written in txt file.

I hope to be useful    :-)